# Problema Jquery y boostrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, npm

Intento instalar boostrap y jquery en mi proyecto pero me sale esta error.

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at Object. (app.js:sourcemap:10906)
    at **webpack_require** (app.js:sourcemap:20)
    at Object._typeof (app.js:sourcemap:1053)
    at **webpack_require** (app.js:sourcemap:20)
    at app.js:sourcemap:63
    at app.js:sourcemap:66
(anonymous) @ app.js:sourcemap:10906
**webpack_require** @ app.js:sourcemap:20
_typeof @ app.js:sourcemap:1053
**webpack_require** @ app.js:sourcemap:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:sourcemap:63
(anonymous) @ app.js:sourcemap:66

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset ('css/app.css') }}">


    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="main" class="container">
        
        @yield('content')
    </div>
        

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instala tus dependencias con npm o intenta usarlo importando directamente las bibliotecas en tu html: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

En [la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#vanilla-js) dice que debes ocupar `scripts` en vez de `js`

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```